# STOMP web socket callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, websocket, stomp

I am trying to connect to a mqtt brocker using STOMP javascript web socket. The connection is made. But the callback function in my code is not called?
But the ping messages are send.

I am using a url as the host address. 
Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>


  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="stomp.js"></script>

  <script>

var ws = new SockJS('http://108.567.234.143:9876/stomp');


var client = Stomp.over(ws);




client.connect('username', 'pw', connect_callback, on_error);


client.heartbeat.outgoing = 20000; // client will send heartbeats every 20000ms
client.heartbeat.incoming = 0;     // client does not want to receive heartbeats
                                   // from the server

var connect_callback = function() {

   alert("Connected to rabbitMQ");
var subscription = client.subscribe("CRICKET", subs_callback);
console.log('subscribe to CRICKET'); 
};

var on_error =  function(error) {
    console.log('error');
};

var    subs_callback = function(message) {
// called when the client receives a STOMP message from the server
if (message.body) {
  alert("got message with body " + message.body)
//console.log('got message with body' + message.body);
} else {
  alert("got empty message");
}
};


console.log('message.body');


</script>


</head>

<body> 


hello world



</body>
</html>
```

I cant subscribe to a topic. Please tell me what is wrong?
[Here is the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEt0d.png)

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Could it be because you defined the callback function, after you've used it? Try placing `client.connect('username', 'pw', connect_callback, on_error);` after the function definitions

Comment: Thank you very much Akum... It worked....

Comment: Awesome, I'll add it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callbacks are being defined after they're used.

It's likely the `.connect()` function is silently ignoring the undefined functions, so you didn't see any errors.

Moving the `.connect()` to after the callbacks are defined, should fix the issue.

```
var ws = new SockJS('http://108.567.234.143:9876/stomp');


var client = Stomp.over(ws);


client.heartbeat.outgoing = 20000; // client will send heartbeats every 20000ms
client.heartbeat.incoming = 0;     // client does not want to receive heartbeats
                                   // from the server

var connect_callback = function() {

   alert("Connected to rabbitMQ");
var subscription = client.subscribe("CRICKET", subs_callback);
console.log('subscribe to CRICKET'); 
};

var on_error =  function(error) {
    console.log('error');
};

var    subs_callback = function(message) {
// called when the client receives a STOMP message from the server
if (message.body) {
  alert("got message with body " + message.body)
//console.log('got message with body' + message.body);
} else {
  alert("got empty message");
}
};


client.connect('username', 'pw', connect_callback, on_error);


console.log('message.body');
```

Comment: As an addition to this, since people may find it useful. If you define the callback function as `function connect_callback() {...` instead of `var connect_callback = function() {...`, then it would work in any order. 
This is due to hoisting, where the browser will load all functions in a file, first.